# How do we encourage people to check an answer

Tags: discussion, questions

How do we go about getting users to check the best answer for their question?  It seems we have a lot of questions that have several up voted answers but no accepted (checked) answers. Is this something that will happen as people get used to how the stack overflow system works?

Answer (score 1):

I don't accept any answer if there isn't one that substantially answers the question. Is that bad?

Comment: Depends.  It can be a hard question, or it could be an unclear question.  If you don't get a good answer start a bounty or rephrase it.

Comment: Though this should be a rare case, it is also possible that a question does not have an answer.

Comment: I would argue that it should be CW if it doesn't have a definitive answer.